# Error while deploying a model on an endpoint- Vertex AI

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm working on a model that I need to deploy on a Vertex AI endpoint. The model is a DNN developed in Tensorflow. I've saved the model locally, loaded to GCS and imported it in the Vertex AI Model section without problems. When I'm trying to deploy it to a new endpoint Vertex responses is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AztD.png)

I've tried to search the error *List of found errors: 1.Field: deployed_model.prediction_resources; Message: Required field is not set.* but found nothing. What could be the cause?

Version of tensorflow and python are the same of the pre-built environment given by Google, the model is saved through tf.keras.Model.save(model, model_path).

Comment: Did you populate either of these fields? `dedicated_resources` or `automatic_resources` on your deploy_model object? See https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.DeployedModel

Comment: Also can you share your code on deploying the model to the endpoint?

Comment: @RiccoD I'm not working with the python library, I've tried to done it with the GUI (also with the CLI, but the parameter are the same of the GUI) and in both case I cannot set that parameter. In fact when I'm trying to deploy the model I cannot set the machine type neither, it let me set just the name of the endpoint and the traffic split.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is not an answer but just want to add more context to this issue. I think this is a bug because the script I had used to upload the model and deploy it to endpoint just failed yesterday because of this error. The weirdest thing is that the error appears when I try to `gcloud ai model list` after successfully uploading the model. More info here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237421435

Comment: Same error with model list here, lets see what google have to say.

Comment: Solved by deploying it through python code. Here can be found some examples of the usage of the python library https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tutorials/jupyter-notebooks . The example of the solution used by me is the following https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/explainable_ai/sdk_custom_tabular_regression_online_explain.ipynb.

Comment: You already know its not an answer.  It should have been a comment.

Comment: @CopyPaster Thanks for your suggestion. I have modified the script to use Python client instead of gcloud command line and it's working now.

Comment: @RohitGupta Agree. I would have commented if I had enough reputation to do so then...